# Expectation Involving Two Values of Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Not sure this is the best place to ask for verification, but I can't seem to find a derivation anywhere else.  I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma(W_t + W_s)}]$, where $W_t$ and $W_s$ are two values of a standard Brownian motion and $\sigma$ is some positive constant.  WLOG assume $s < t$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the filtration generated by the Brownian motion.  Then using standard results I get

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma(W_t + W_s)}] & = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma(W_t - W_s)}e^{2\sigma W_s}| \mathcal{F}_s]] \\ 
& = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{\sigma(W_t - W_s)}]e^{2\sigma W_s}] \\
& = \mathbb{E}[e^{2\sigma W_s}]e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t-s)} \\
& = e^{2\sigma^2 s + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t-s)} \\
& = e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(3s + t)}.
\end{align*}
$$

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to use "Brownian motion" for "normal random variable".

Comment: I've used properties of Brownian motion in the derivation, namely independence and known distribution of its increments.

Comment: Then $W_s$ and $W_t$ would be two values of **the same** Brownian motion $W$ at times $t$ and $s$--in which case you need to seriously revise the question.

Comment: Seriously revised.

Comment: Much better now... :-) If every $1/2 \sigma^2$ in your answer is actually $\sigma^2/2$, then the answer is correct.

Comment: Excellent, just clarified those fractions.  Thanks for the time!