# Variance of Integrated Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm just asking for verification that my derivation is correct, as I can't seem to find this result elsewhere.  I'd like to calculate $Var(\int_0^T X(t) dt)$ where $X(t) = X_0e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t + \sigma W(t)}$, $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion and $\mu, \sigma$ and $T$ are constants.  By definition
$$
\operatorname{Var}\left(\int_0^T X(t) dt\right) = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T\int_0^T X(t)X(s) dt ds\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T X(t) dt\right]^2.
$$
Assuming $\mu \neq 0$ the second term is easily calculated to be (neglecting the square)
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T X(t) dt\right] & = \int_0^T \mathbb{E}\left[X(t)\right] dt \\
& = \int_0^T X_0e^{\mu t} dt \\
& = \frac{X_0}{\mu}(e^{\mu T} - 1).
\end{align*}
$$
The first term is a bit nastier.  Assume $\mu \neq 0$, $\mu + \sigma^2 \neq 0$, and $2\mu + \sigma^2 \neq 0$ (these terms appear in denominators after the final integration, which is left out).  Then using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811647/expectation-involving-two-values-of-geometric-brownian-motion?noredirect=1#comment1677379_811647) result with no restriction on the order of $s,t$ to get from the second to the third line I get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^T\int_0^T X(t)X(s) dt ds\right] & = \int_0^T\int_0^T \mathbb{E}\left[X(t)X(s) \right] dt ds \\
& = X_0^2\int_0^T\int_0^T e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(t+s)}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\sigma(W_t + W_s)} \right] dt ds  \\
& = X_0^2\int_0^T\int_0^T e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(t+s)} e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(3\min\{s,t\} + \max\{s,t\})} dt ds \\
& = X_0^2\int_0^T\int_0^s e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(t+s)} e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(3t + s)} dt \\
& \qquad + \int_s^T e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(t+s)} e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(3s + t)} dtds \\
& = X_0^2\int_0^T\left(\int_0^s e^{\mu s} e^{(\mu + \sigma^2)t} dt + \int_s^T e^{\mu t} e^{(\mu + \sigma^2)s} dt\right) ds.
\end{align*} 
$$
The rest is just a tedious integration.
If anyone knows where I can find another derivation of this to compare with my result it would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The step where you use $\exp(\frac12\sigma^2(3s+t))$ is wrong since one needs $s\lt t$ there.

Comment: @Did I assumed that above.  And hi again.

Comment: It seems that you did not, since you integrate for every $(s,t)$ in $[0,T]\times[0,T]$.

Comment: @Did good catch, let me look at this more in detail and revise my derivation.

Comment: OK. Here is a suggestion: the function you integrate is symmetric in $(s,t)$ hence you could integrate it twice on the triangle $0\lt s\lt t\lt T$.

Comment: @Did do you mean $e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(t+s)}$ is symmetric in $(s,t)$?  I don't see how the entire integrand $e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(t+s)} e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(3s + t)}$ is symmetric in $(s,t)$.  Simplifying the integrand to the form on the 4th line, it's of the form $e^{as + bt}$, $a,b$ being constants, and I don't see how this is symmetric in $(s,t)$ :/

Comment: Earlier on, in the line with $W_t+W_s$, everything is still symmetric.

Comment: @Did Ok, I actually removed the assumption on the order of $s,t$ and just broke up the domain of integration to account for each case.  Does this look better?

Comment: The new version is correct. You might want to compute only one term in the RHS and multiply it by $2$ since both terms are the same.

Comment: @Did excellent.  Can't thank you enough for your time!